# new domain not finding install.php for multisite

Tags: multi-sites

Don't know what is going on here except that this time instead of adding a subdomain for my multisite I am adding a new domain which is already pointing to same IP.

I have set it up exactly as subdomain except obviously the name in sites folder reflects another domain name.

When I go to the new domain address it links only to the root of the site and not the root of the drupal folder.

I have firstsite.com (links to plain html)

then sub.firstsite.com (links to drupal root folder)

then sub2.firstsite.com (links to drupal root folder by way of sites folder)

then secondsite.com (links to plain html even though on drupal root sites folder)

I NEED secondsite.com to behave in same way as sub2.firstsite.com

MY SET UP FOR VHOSTS

/etc/httpd/conf.d/my.conf

vi my.conf

## my rules

NameVirtualHost *:80

ServerName firstsite.net
ServerAlias www.firstsite.net
ServerAdmin vps@firstsite.net
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

AllowOverride All
Allow from all

ServerName sub1.firstsite.net
ServerAlias www.sub1.firstsite.net
ServerAdmin vps@sub1.firstsite.net
VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/html/drupal"

ServerName sub2.firstsite.net
ServerAlias www.sub2.firstsite.net
ServerAdmin vps@sub2.firstsite.net
VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/html/drupal"

ServerName secondsite.com
ServerAlias www.secondsite.com
ServerAdmin vps@secondsite.com
VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/html/drupal"

ServerName localhost

Comment: Is this Drupal 6 or 7? If it's 7, have you created a file called `sites.php` inside the `sites` directory? (So ultimately it'd be located at `sites/sites.php`) If you need examples of how to configure said file, you should see an existing file called `example.sites.php` inside the `sites` directory...

Comment: Drupal 7 and my aliases are listed in /etc/httpd/conf.d/my.conf

Comment: I haven't had to use that file for my other site which works just fine- why would I need it for this one?

Comment: @Charlie multi sites cant work without a properly formed sites.php file. Just copy the example file and tweak it as required

Comment: I already have multi sites working without the sites.php

Comment: @Clive, it can work if there's a simple and straight mapping from domain names to directory names, though a sites configuration makes it more explicit.

@ CharlieBunt I don't actually understand your vhost setup, can you show the relevant/important vhost conf and directory contents? I've had similar issues a lot of times, it's almost always a vhost problem causing Drupal not to understand which domain is being requested.

Comment: @Charlie is there any harm in adding it to see if it fixes the problem? It would only take 30 seconds

Comment: no harm at all, I will add it.

Comment: @Letharion interesting, that's not my experience with multi sites, I've always needed a sites.php. Maybe the vhost settings were off as you suggest

Comment: multisites is working for all sites listed above excepting secondsite.com

Comment: Just to be clear, are you trying to serve static pages from a drupal directory? This could be post DrupalCon jetlag, but I don't understand why you'd expect that to work similarly to serving a Drupal site from the same directory.
@Clive if you check bootstraps conf_path(), you'll see that Drupal makes a naive attempt to set the sites dir based on $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. Most of the time this is enough for my setups. :)

Comment: No I'm def not trying to serve static pages from a drupal directory. Drupal resides in the first subdomain and multi-sites run off that...like sub2 works perfectly well. Just unable to configure with a new domain url. STATIC pages only reside in the root of first site which is obviously non drupal.

Comment: I think this has something to do with not being able to declare a directory more than once in the conf file and I think the clue I'm getting but could be unrelated, is when restarting service httpd and get two warnings saying no nameservers named.

Comment: The weird thing is currently secondsite.com is directing to /var/www/html even though explicitly directed it to go to /html/drupal and if try and force it in browser to that drupal folder it gives exception base table or view not found<another clue.

Comment: maybe it is as simple as have not set up db correctly- will look into it further tomorrow- know it is something simple because every other multisite i did work out started by directing to the html folder!